# 23 files found with path 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' from inputs:

Tags: android, react-native, expo, detox

I've been running `detox build -c android.emu.debug` and I keep getting an this error:

```
23 files found with path 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' from inputs:
```

Which seems to be coming from `shopify_react-native-skia:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource`.
Any suggestions on how to about this will help.

## **Environment**

- Expo: SDK 48
- Flow: Bare
- Device: Android

## **Solutions tried**

- Disable zipflinger in gradle.properties

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

- Excluding all files below at build time in app, build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
}
```

## **Solutions tried**

- Expected all files named `"META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"` to be excluded at build time.